# jQuery responsive navigation delay

Tags: jquery, plugins, responsive-design

Right now I am using two plugins listed below. The second plugin is causing the first plugin (http://www.berriart.com/sidr/#development) to delay. I can't figure out why. Here is my website http://www.jonasandnicole.com in which you have to shrink the navigation to see the mobile navigation.

Sidr jQuery

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#simple-menu').sidr();
});
</script>
```

Smooth Scroll jQuery

```
<script src="js/jquery.easing.1.3.js"></script>
<script>
$(function() {
var lengthDiv = $('.desktop').find('li').length;
var current = 0;
$('a').bind('click',function(event){

var $anchor = $(this);
current = $anchor.parent().index();

$('html, body').stop().animate({
    scrollTop: $($anchor.attr('href#')).offset().top
}, 1500,'easeInOutExpo');
/*
if you don't want to use the easing effects:
$('html, body').stop().animate({
    scrollTop: $($anchor.attr('href')).offset().top
}, 1000);
*/
event.preventDefault();
});
$(document).keydown(function(e){if($(':focus').length <= 0)e.preventDefault()})
$(document).keyup(function(e){
    var key = e.keyCode;
    if(key == 38 && current > 0){
        $('.desktop').children('li').eq(current - 1).children('a').trigger('click')
    }else if(key == 40 && current < lengthDiv){
        $('.desktop').children('li').eq(current + 1).children('a').trigger('click')
    }
})
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Javascripts execute in the order that they're included on the page. I would at least recommend using the defer (and maybe async) attribute on things like retina.js that can run independently really. Consider moving those scripts that are giving you troubles into another file as well so you can use the same techniques there.

I see a slight delay if I click the menu element as soon as I see it but if I wait just a little bit for everything to finish executing (Chrome 27) I see no delay. Sounds like this is just a performance tuning thing where you need to get your other items executing asynchronously and deferred so your `sidr` call can finish first.

Comment: jxpx777 I am using     if (matchMedia('only screen and (min-width: 480px)').matches) {     statement to call functions as I need them. It seems to work if I just start out on a small screen but if I expand it my desktop navigation doesn't work. Do you recommend this? If so how would I get the other desktop navigation to work if I expanded the window?

Comment: Try using `window.matchMedia` and add an event listener on the returned MediaQueryList object. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.matchMedia